# if statement fails to evaluate to true even though condition is met in django template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to check if a dictionary key list contains an element in django template. I can see the element in the list but the if statement returns false

```
{% if item in incart %}
  1
{% else %}
  0
{% endif %}
```

when I do

```
{{incart}}
```

it produces dict_keys(['1', '2'])

and

```
{{item}}
```

shows 2

However when I run the statement above

```
{% if item in incart %}
  1
{% else %}
  0
{% endif %}
```

it returns 0 instead of 1.

What are my doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `item`? Is it a string or integer?

Comment: is it 2 or "2". This is probably the fact that one is a string and the other is an int

Comment: Try `if str(item) in incart`

Comment: What are `item` and `incart`?

Comment: item returns 2 not '2', while incart returns dict_keys(['1', '2'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry guys, I didn't furnish enough information. The `{{ item }}` variable is a key from django's `request.session`. It states in the documentation that session keys are supposed to be strings, and anything other than this, won't behave properly https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.clear . The mistake was on my part, I was using an integer instead of a string, as some persons rightly pointed out.

Thank you